# How to use mockito's matcher to call specified method when anyInt() not worked

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new to mockito. when I use it with junit, I found anyInt() not working, the example code is as following:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MockitoDemo {
    @Test
    public void verify_doB_method_invoked() {
        MockitoAnyIntMatcherDemo mockitoAnyIntMatcherDemo = Mockito.mock(MockitoAnyIntMatcherDemo.class);
        when(mockitoAnyIntMatcherDemo.doA(anyInt())).thenReturn(1);
        
        verify(mockitoAnyIntMatcherDemo, times(1)).doB(anyInt());
    }
}

class MockitoAnyIntMatcherDemo {
    public int doA(int a) {
        return doB(a);
    }
    public int doB(int b) {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated。

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You never called `doA` in your test.

`when` method is used for stubbing - it is like recording expected calls and answers to them.

You successfully stubbed `doA` method - you recorded the expectation: "if `doA` is called in the test with any int argument, then return 1".

As you never called `doA` in your test, verify rightfully reports it was not called.

On top of that - in the example you provided you mock the object under test.
This is not what mocking is typically used for.